# Is it possible to track subfolders using Google Analytics from one file?

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

Let's say this is my directory structure:

```
ROOT
index.php -- Folder 1 -> file.php
          -- Folder 2 -> file.php
            |-- subfolder -> file.php
          -= Folder 3 -> file.php
```

and I need to put my tracking code on my index.php file, but I need this single code to track the activity on every single folder that is a child of the folder where index.php is.

I just need to insert the tracking code on index.php, or should I do something else, like using a php `require` commend?

EDIT:
Finally made it, here is how I've put things to work:
[Insert Google Analytics in php (Am I doing it the right way?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30268353/insert-google-analytics-in-php-am-i-doing-it-the-right-way?noredirect=1#comment48637094_30268353)

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en)? They couldn't possibly make their instructions any clearer: _"Add the tracking code directly into the HTML of **every page of your website**."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, you will want the Analytics tracking code to appear on every page of your site you wish to track.

Once solution could be to include your tracking code in a PHP file (say, *analytics.php*), and `require` it after opening the `<body>` tag of your pages.

Comment: Thank you. That's going to be enough.